# How linux(eg Ubuntu) GUI shutdown works with local user priviledge but not via commandline

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown

When trying to shutdown the computer from command line, it asks for root password but not when shutting down from the Unity or other Desktop environments. Is there any way this can be done from command line? Without entering the root password like the GUI does.

Comment: I think this should answer you question,

http://askubuntu.com/questions/168879/shutdown-from-terminal-without-entering-password

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should belongs to other sites of StackExchange networks such as askunbuntu or unix and linux (and it already has answers there)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DBUS to talk to programs that already run with root priviliges to do the poweroff for you:

```
#PowerOff
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff boolean:true

#Suspending
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

These work on my Linux Mint 17.1, MATE edition, with mdm.

You can save these as executable (chmod +x) scripts somewhere in your $PATH and use those scripts to do user-level power-management operations from the command line.

This all depends on the `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` being correctly set in your environment (will be in you're in virtual terminals inside an X session, but not if your run from a tty virtual console (Ctr-Alt+F) -- then you will have to copy the value from your X session.